How to utilize StrawberryShake tools for schema located in github
I am trying to add strawberry shake to a project for my first time using GraphQL in .NET and I am struggling to get the tooling to work to build the client for strawberry shake to work. The code I am trying to use is:
dotnet graphql init https://github.com/Enterprise-CMCS/managed-care-review/blob/main/services/app-graphql/src/schema.graphql TestClient

I thought the point of this command was to pull the schema but unfortunately I keep receiving a 403 forbidden error in the terminal despite this is a public repo and should not even require a token. In examples I have seen they do not reference the schema file but instead the endpoint (ie, blahblah.com/graphql) so maybe I should not be referencing the file?

This question has gone unanswered for quite some time. I suspect the OP has found a workaround or a solution, but for others that might find themselves here from a search engine.
In this case, where you are not generating against a running server, you can manually download the schema and generate from that local file.
This command:
curl -o DownloadedSchema/ManagedCareSchema.graphql https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Enterprise-CMCS/managed-care-review/refs/heads/main/services/app-graphql/src/schema.graphql

will download the schema from the original post.
Then you can run:
dotnet graphql init -f DownloadedSchema/ManagedCareSchema.graphql -n ManagedCareGraphQlClient -p ./ManagedCareClient

This command uses the downloaded file, specified by the -f argument to initialize a client named ManagedCareGraphQlClient in the project in the folder ./ManagedCareClient.
The complete sequence of commands to create a solution on macOS or Unix would look like this:
# Generate the solution with a class library and console app.
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install StrawberryShake.Tools --local
dotnet new sln -n ManagedCareClient
dotnet new classlib --name ManagedCareClient
dotnet add ManagedCareClient package StrawberryShake.Server
dotnet sln add ./ManagedCareClient
dotnet new console --name ManagedCareClient.Cli
dotnet sln add ./ManagedCareClient.Cli

# Downloading schema

mkdir DownloadedSchema
curl -o DownloadedSchema/ManagedCareSchema.graphql https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Enterprise-CMCS/managed-care-review/refs/heads/main/services/app-graphql/src/schema.graphql

# Fix typo in schema

sed -i 's/"\\/./g' DownloadedSchema/ManagedCareSchema.graphql

# Initialize the GraphQL client

dotnet graphql init -f DownloadedSchema/ManagedCareSchema.graphql -n ManagedCareGraphQlClient -p ./ManagedCareClient

# Build the solution

dotnet build

The sed command is there to remove what I suspect is a typo in the schema mentioned in the original post; it would not normally be needed.
It should be straightforward to adapt this to Windows cmd or PowerShell

I did find a workaround for now by accessing my APIs dev environment but this is extremely useful regardless since for our project github is the source of truth. I am accepting this as an answer. Thank you for putting the time into solving this for myself and anyone who comes across it.

Just curious though. is the reason I get the forbidden error is because the dotnet graphql init is looking for introspect enabled and github isnt using that?

@Qiuzman Yes, when you supply a URL, it tries to send an introspection query to that URL. The GitHub server, understandably enough, is not expecting this!
